Finding the limit using sandwich
I got stuck finding :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+ \dots +n^n}}{1+2+\dots+n}$$
here is what i did:
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}}_{\underbrace{\to \space0}_{n\to \infty}} = \frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^n}}{n^2}\overbrace{\leq}^{*}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+ \dots +n^n}}{1+2+\dots+n}\overbrace{\leq}^{**}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n \cdot n^n}}{n}=\frac{\overbrace{\sqrt[n]{n}}^{\underbrace{\to \space1}_{n\to \infty}} \space n}{n}=1$$
$(*)=n^2>1+2+\dots+n \quad\text{and} \quad \sqrt[n]{n^n}< \sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+ \dots +n^n}$
$(**) =\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+ \dots +n^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{n \cdot n^n} \quad\text{and} \quad n<1+2+3+\cdots+n$
what did I do wrong or what did I miss?

At (**) your estimate of $1+2+\dots+n$ is too crude, the sum is $\frac{n(n+1}{2}$ and if you use that you will be squeezed to $0$.

Instead of $$n \le 1+2+3+\dots+n, $$ you may use $$ \frac{n^2}{2} \le 1+2+3+\dots+n, $$
which could add some meaning to your sandwich.

but how would i know that the limit is supposed to go to $0$ ?

You would get $2\sqrt[n]{n}n/n^2$ instead of $\sqrt[n]{n}n/n$. Since you know that $\sqrt[n]{n}\to1$ and $2n/n^2\to0$, then the product $\to0$.

As an alternative by AM-GM
$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+ \dots +n^n}}{1+2+\dots+n}\le \frac{\sqrt[n]{n \cdot n^n}}{n\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{(n-1)!}}$$
